# How to use Slim inside assets? with Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

I'm trying to use Slim template inside assets.

I placed slim file in /app/assets/template/test.html.slim

and when I access /assets/test.html it say

"No route matches [GET] "/assets/login.html"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're expecting a javascript template, have you tried accessing it as:
`JST['template/test']`?